# class accessible from all other classes

Tags: java, android

I have some database functions and would like to make those database functions accessible too all of my other classes. I would like to keep the functions in one place so they are easy to modify. What is the best way to achieve this goal? My application is running on android and is using threading and events.

Thanks in advance, if you need more information let me know.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- make a class with all static methods/variables, or alternatively a Singleton
- synchronize stuff if you need to, sounds like you might

Comment: Can you elaborate on synchronize. I have seen it discussed before with java and android and have yet to understand its use. Does it force calls to the functions onto a stack that waits for stuff to resolve before allowing others to call the specific function?

Comment: basically, synchronized functions can only be entered into by 1 thread at a time; other threads wait. Once you start talking multiple threads, synchronization becomes important - read up on that

Answer (score 2):

Absolutely no reason why you can't have a package level class called something like `DatabaseUtils` and put general static methods in there. Doesn't have much bearing on it that you're using threading and events, although you will want to ensure your utility methods can handle simultaneous access if that's a possibility.

Comment: I am going to use a singleton, since this was my initial idea. I just wanted to see if there were any alternatives that were extremely better. Thanks.